# Select bounding box Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, region

I am trying to select a particular region (square) on map of ERA5 dataset but `ee.Geometry.BBox` instead add the layer on the whole map instead of that squared region. I have region coordinates inside ee.Geometry.BBox and I want the wind map for only inside this region.
Here is my code:

```
var region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.09, 37.42, -122.08, 37.43); // Dummy coordinates

var ERA5 = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
                              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'))
var bbox2 = region.bounds()
var bbox = ERA5.filterBounds(bbox2)

var visParams = {
  bands: ['u_component_of_wind_10m'],
  min: -40.0,
  max: 35.0,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(bbox2, visParams, 'Wind')
Map.addLayer(ERA5, {}, 'Wind')
```

How do I select squared region?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.
If you are asking about selecting the region, then you can clip the imahe by .clip.

If you want the ERA5 map to be displayed below the region, then write the line addLayer bbox2 at last.

```
Map.addLayer(ERA5, {}, 'Wind')
Map.addLayer(bbox2, visParams, 'Wind')
```

But the question is not clear.

Comment: clip is for ```ee.Image``` but I am using ```ee.ImageCollection```. I have region coordinates inside ```ee.Geometry.BBox``` and I want the wind map for only inside this region.

Comment: For that you can map a function for your image collection.

Comment: I have managed to crop the region by using ```var ERA5 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY')
.filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'))
.select('u_component_of_wind_10m').first())``` but ```.first()``` gives me only first image in the collection, but I want to get all 24 images for 24 hours, How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Solved ```var ERA5List = ERA5Collection.toList(ERA5Collection.size())
var ERA5 = ee.Image(ERA5List.get(22))``` for 22th hour of u component of wind